# What is the difference between '>-' and '|-' in yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I wanted to know exactly what is the difference between '>-' and  '|-' especially in kubernetes yaml manifests

Comment: https://yaml-multiline.info/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Newlines in folded block scalars (`>`) are subject to line folding, newlines in literal block scalars (`|`) are not.

Line folding replaces a single newline between non-empty lines with a space, and in the case of empty lines, reduces the number of newline characters between the surrounding non-empty lines by one:

```yaml
a: > # folds into "one two\nthree four\n\nfive\n"
  one
  two

  three
  four


  five
```

Line folding does not occur between lines when at least one line is more indented, i.e. contains whitespace at the beginning that is not part of the block's general indentation:

```yaml
a: > # folds into "one\n  two\nthree four\n\n five\n"
  one
    two
  three
  four

   five
```

Adding `-` after either `|` or `>` will strip the newline character from the last line:

```yaml
a: >- # folded into "one two"
  one
  two
b: >- # folded into "one\ntwo"
  one

  two
```

In contrast, `|` emits every newline character as-is, the sole exception being the last one if you use `-`.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I got one main difference between > and | from here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html

> Values can span multiple lines using | or >. Spanning multiple lines
> using a “Literal Block Scalar” | will include the newlines and any
> trailing spaces. Using a “Folded Block Scalar” > will fold newlines to
> spaces; it’s used to make what would otherwise be a very long line
> easier to read and edit. In either case the indentation will be
> ignored.

Examples are:

```
include_newlines: |
            exactly as you see
            will appear these three
            lines of poetry

fold_newlines: >
            this is really a
            single line of text
            despite appearances
```

In fact the ">" is in my understanding, the equivalent of the escape characters '\' at the end of a bash script for example

If one can tell me what is the "-" used for in kubernetes yaml manifests it will complete my understanding :)

Comment: This link has a good explanation and pretty examples, https://yaml-multiline.info/.
In summary, `-` means removing newlines at the end of the block, regardless of how many newlines there is. and `+` means keep all of the newlines that exist in the block