# Can anyone explain what this means (|-) in a Kubernetes yaml

Tags: kubernetes

This is a yaml of a config map I came across ?

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: foobar
  namespace: ksys
data:
  cloud-config: |-
    address: "cloud-provider-service:8085"
```

Can anyone tell me what `|-` means here ? Any link that would give me more info ? Is this yaml specific or Kubernetes specific ?

Comment: Not specific to k8s, it is just general yaml syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between '>-' and '|-' in yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72082343/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-yaml)

Comment: @Turing85 the link you posted does not talk about `|-`

Comment: Oh you mean execpt for the fact that it is in the title, and the 1st answer expalins `|`, `>`, `|-`, `>-` and the differences between them?

Comment: https://yaml-multiline.info/ also provides a nice interactive interfact to help you understand this

Answer (score 0):

`|` will indicate this block contains newlines and `-` indicates strip away the last newline of this block. In simple terms, `|-` will let your lines in the block be separated by newline and strip the newline at the end of the block or cloud-config.